# Permissions for writing a file

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, web-services, winforms

I've the following issue

- I've a windows application
- It calls a remote web service (for authentication)
- It in turns call a web service (in the same remote machine) (to get a licensed file)
- It saves the licensed file in All Users/Application Data in the system where the application is running

Which permission is used for saving the file in the Application Data folder? Either the web service's or the currently logged windows user's?

**Update #1**

So, i'm not able to save the license as the web service call is throwing a save error. How can i check the permissions of the folder?

Here is the code for creating my folder

```
licensePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "MyApp");
            if (!Directory.Exists(licensePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(licensePath);
```

**Update #2**

If i try to save it in the application's path itself (in bin/debug while debugging the application), it is working fine. Any ideas? I've tried just "C:\test" too. It's not working.

Thank you.

Regards
NLV

Comment: Can you clarify what "it" is at each step of your workflow?

Comment: It refers to my windows application. I've proxy classes in my application and i'm connecting to the remote web services. The remote services, after all the checking, will save a file in the system (licensing info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will save the file with the permissions of the user that is running the windows application (which can be different from the logged in user - see [`RunAs`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx)).

Comment: Great! But i'm running the application as a local administrator. (My system is in a domain. But i've assigned my account as the local administrator for my machine). So what could be the problem? How can i check the permissions?

Comment: You asked about what user the application saves as. Is there a different problem that you did not ask? Please update your question with further details.

Comment: What version of Windows?  With Windows Vista and 7, you'll be running with a restricted token and unable to write to the All Users area, even if the user account is an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The permission the windows application is running in.